# Can't do anything on startup until terminating Kate in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kate

When my Kubuntu starts i can't do anything until starting System Activity and killing Kate. I can not start any program or for example run Dolphin file manager. After terminating Kate a message is shown:

[image]

Afterwards everything is OK. How may i solve this problem?

Comment: Try to reinstall kate by running this command on terminal `sudo apt-get install --reinstall kate`

Comment: I tries it. Did not solve the problem.

Comment: You could always remove it... `sudo apt-get remove kate` - alternatives include [`gedit`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gedit/), [`mousepad`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/mousepad/) and [`leafpad`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/leafpad/) if you need any - more [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/15-ubuntu-text-editors-grab-your-favorite/) as well.

Comment: To add to @Wilf's suggestion, you can change the default editor by going to `System Settings` > `File Associations` > `application` > `x-shellscript` and changing the order of items in `Application Preference Order`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that i had a shell script in my /home/user/.kde/Autostart folder which was supposed to run on start. But i had not changed its mode to executable. Changing the mode by "sudo chmod +x " solved the problem.

Comment: Same problem, same solution. Mine was the `setlocale.sh` script in the autostart folder.